# Receive email notifications from Stackdriver for Apps Script project errors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, error-logging, stackdriver

I have a Apps Script project with a trigger that is logging to "Stackdriver Logging" and "Stackdriver Error Reporting". I want to receive emailed notifications when my triggered script has errors, so I am following this guide:
https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/notifications

However for step 3 ("In the resulting Communication dialog, select Error Reporting in the Product column") I receive the error message:

> "You don't have any projects yet."

Any ideas?
[image: Error message i am seeing]

Comment: Apps Script projects are auto-created with hidden Google Cloud Platform projects. You might need to migrate to a "real" GCP project first: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects

Comment: @tehhowch, this is a valid response that I would recommend that you post as an answer to give it more visibility and collect well-deserved points.

Comment: @fady it's a note that should be readily apparent given any research into "Apps Script Google Cloud Platform" by any OP. (literally the top search result in an incognito window)